# What chemicals could be used to repair rubber tires?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I have a beaten old R/C car that I am restoring for my son. It has some nice rubber tires on it, but they are kind of old and worn. The rubber itself is almost moldy and looks matte.

I could just fetch some wonderful product of a shelf somewhere that promises to restore the rubber, but I would like to really know what can be done for old rubber on a low level.

So, how can I treat my rubber, and which chemical process works best (if any)?